# EPPlus Off-by-One Fix

Tags: c#, epplus, off-by-one

I'm updating some old code, and want to replace some code to create excel documents with EPPlus. The problem is my old code indexes things from [0, n-1] and EPPlus indexes from [1, n].

Is there any way to account for this, other than to manually increment all cell addresses by [1,1]?

Comment: I think one way to go about this would be to create something to interface the two, like an ExcelRangeCustom object that would take in [0,n-1] and make the ExcelRange calls with +1 to all the row/column indices.

I'm just not quite sure how to do that, nor if that really is a decent idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So an interface which reads in indices at [0,n-1] and then increments the values before calling the appropriate methods probably would have worked, but for personal reasons, I couldn't use this approach.

Things that helped me:

- Where I was using variables purposed for indexing, I could increase their initial value by 1.
- Large sections of relatively repetitive code (same operations, different cell ranges) into small loops where there were less values to manage.
- Helper methods for commonly used formats for were also very helpful in preventing me writing the same range multiple times.

Beyond that, however, I unfortunately didn't find a simpler way than to add [1,1] to everything.